# How to insert a footline with default beamer theme

Tags: beamer, lyx, beamerposter

I've inserted the `\title` and `\author` in my latex preamble to be shown in the footline at the end of my poster. When using `\usepackage{beamerthemedefault}` the footline won't show. How do I display this footline using the default beamer theme?

```
\documentclass[10pt,english,final]{beamer}
\makeatletter
\usepackage{beamerthemedefault}
\usecolortheme{default}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=1.4,debug]{beamerposter}

\title{Research Report Poster STK795}
\author{AUTHOR HERE \\ Department University}
\date{15 October 2016}
\usepackage{mwe} % just for dummy images
\usebackgroundtemplate%
{%
     \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image}%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Should have the footline at the bottom like this:
[image: Imgur]

Comment: Please make a real MWE

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem. (See more details on [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228))

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose. (All these rules might seem tedious, but they are what makes this site really useful!)

Comment: I have shortened the code substantially now.

Comment: I won't answer your question, because I don't have enough knowledge/skills. However, here are a few more hints on how you could continue to shorten your example in order to make it *minimal*: are several text blocks necessary to reproduce the problem? and what about the background image? In the same way, you don't have to include all settings about text color (`\usebeamercolor`). ` \setcounter`s are not necessary here, as well as loading `amsmath`, `amssymb`, etc. packages. (But please, don't take this comment bad or personnaly: we've all learned how to produce a really minimal example!)

Comment: Can you make a sketch of how the result should look like? `beamerposter` seems to have problems with footnotes, but maybe there is a workaround?

Comment: I have added an image of how it should look

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhh, now that make sense. Wait a sec.

Comment: Yeah it works when one uses any other theme. Just not with the default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bring back the footline by setting the respective beamer template:

```
\documentclass[10pt,english,final]{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemedefault}
\usecolortheme{default}
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=1.4,debug]{beamerposter}

\title{Research Report Poster STK795}
\author{AUTHOR HERE}
\institute{Department University}
\date{15 October 2016}
\usepackage{mwe} % just for dummy images
\usebackgroundtemplate%
{%
     \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image}%
}

\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{bg=blue, fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{bg=blue!50!black, fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{institute in head/foot}{fg=white}

% slightly modified from beamerouterthememiniframes.sty
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line foot}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{author in head/foot}%
      \leavevmode{\usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor}%
      \space%
%      \hfill%
      {\usebeamerfont{institute in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{institute in head/foot}\insertshortinstitute}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}%
      {\usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line foot}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
bla
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ishido This is not a footnote :) But yes, you can make it transparent by removing the definition of the background colours. Replace the definition in the above code by `\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{institute in head/foot}{fg=black}`

Comment: Ah yes i just found that out. Thank you for the effort samcarter